# I want to send email (send as) with C# to Office365 but I get an error

Tags: c#, .net, email

As I've written in the title, I get an error:

> 5.7.62 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send on behalf of the from address

I want to use C# to send an email using account2, but as if it were account1. Which means that account2 will send the email, but when the recipient receives the email, they will see account1 as the sender.

But if I use another account (not from Office365) instead of account2 (real sender), there is no exception.

Or if I use another account (not from Office365) instead of account1 (display sender), there is no exception.

And if I send with foxmail client, everything is right.

I've tried to search the problem on the internet for a few days, but still cannot solve this problem. Can you give me some advice?

My code:

```
static public void Send(string from, string fromDisplay, string fromPwd, string to, string toDisplayName) 
{
    //account1: an  account from a office365 email server to (to display on the sender when received)
        var emailFrom = new MailAddress("EmailToDisplayToReceiver@<theserver>.com", "test");

        //account2:The sender is another account from an office365 email server(The real sender to send the email )
        var sender = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from, fromDisplay); 
        System.Net.Mail.MailAddress EmailTo = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(to, toDisplayName);
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Email = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(emailFrom, EmailTo);
        Email.Sender = sender;
        Email.Body = "The content";
        Email.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
        Email.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
        Email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        Email.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;

        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SmtpPC = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587); 
        SmtpPC.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        SmtpPC.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpPC.UseDefaultCredentials=false;

        //the real sender and password
        SmtpPC.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, fromPwd);  
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = RemoteCertificateValidationCallback;
        try
        {
            SmtpPC.Send(Email);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
        //Here throwed an exception which said:
        //Mailbox is unable to use.The server response is: 5.7.62 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send on behalf of the from address
        //(邮箱不可用。 服务器响应为: 5.7.62 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send on behalf of the from address)
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error you're seeing is pretty self explanatory, what more help do you need?

Comment: It's exactly as the error says, the credentials you're using to authenticate don't have permission to send as the other address. Assign the permissions in Exchange and the error will go away. This is not a code issue.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because the error message tells you exactly what's wrong. There's no open question to answer here. The advice would be to grant the permission that the error message says is missing.

Comment: Thanks for you advice.But I still confuse on these three situations: I can send success on foxmail client with the same account,if the account2 does not have the permission to send as the account1.

Comment: 2. I can send when I use other email instead of the account1. 3 I can send when I use other email address instead of the account2. Besides the email server is belong to my customer far away from where  work,so I can not see the permission settings on the mail server to check on it.

Comment: On the error message "Client does not have permissions to send ", the client here is the email account of the program which execute the send action?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the from address is fake or is not defined in the directory in which you are trying to send email on behalf of. There a couple of things to try:

- Try giving the authenticating account proper `Send As` / `On Behalf Of` permissions to the `From` address account.
- Make sure the actual email header `From` and `Sender` are using the same address.
- Giving the `sender` account permissions on each `From` user.

If you need more info you can check out [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919240(v=exchg.150).aspx) link, and read the `Use shell to assign permissions` section.

Comment: Thanks for you advice.But what make me confuse is that I can send the email with the same account with foxmail client,also my customer can send the email use outlook.

Comment: I need: `From: xxxx@MYDOMAIN.com` and `Sender:  YYY@MYDOMAIN.com`